# date time formate problem in ssql server 2005(asp.net) please correct me

Tags: asp.net

i am using debugger following is my code when i give input for date `dateOfBirth is=10/08/2010`   (dd//mm/yy format) but the birthDate variable having value={1/10/2010 12:08:00 AM} 
and string outPut have value=08/10/YY
and on taking my debugger to next step to `date=Convert.ToDateTime(outPut)`  it throws exception "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 6."
Whats wrong with all this please let me know how to convert date time format `dd/mm/yyyy` to date for mate for sql server 2005

following is my code

```
  DateTime? date = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DOB.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        string dateOfBirth = DOB.Text.Trim();
                        DateTime birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirth, "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        string outPut = birthDate.ToString("mm/dd/YY");
                        date = Convert.ToDateTime(outPut);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I understand what you are trying to do now, Convert a 'dd/MM/yyyy' date to a DateTime, the following code should do it

```
      DateTime? date = null;
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DOB.Text.Trim()))
      {
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
        dateInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"; 
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text.Trim(), dateInfo);
      }
```

Comment: no it doesnt work. I am having date in DD/MM/YYYY format and i want it to change in database format mm/dd/yy so what to do

Comment: The first setence is not true, you can convert a mm/dd/yy to a date.  It will also automatically detect the century for you ie. Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/99") knows 1999 and Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/00") knows 2000

Comment: @Snow, I just tried it and I stand corrected, I've edited my post to reflect the answer to his intended question

Answer (score 0):

you have format string mixed up:
`MM` (uppercase) is the double digit month
`mm` (lowercase) is double digit minutes

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`string outPut = birthDate.ToString("mm/dd/YY");`

To:

`string outPut = birthDate.ToString("mm/dd/yy");`

Like you said, your string is returning "08/10/YY".  Notice the 'YY'